# Regular expression - match all words but match unique words only once

Tags: regex

Is it possible to use a regular expression to match all words but match unique words only once? **I am aware there are other ways of doing this however I'm interested in knowing if this is possible with the use of a regular expression.**

For example I currently have the following expression:

```
(\w+\b)(?!.*\1)
```

and the following string:

```
glass shoes door window door glasses. window glasses
```

For the most part the expression works and matches the following words:

```
shoes
door 
window
glasses
```

There are two issues with this:

1. A match for a substring is being made on "glasses" with "glass",
   this is incorrect.
2. "glasses" and "glasses." should match but currently do not.

The final match should be:

```
shoes 
door 
window 
glasses 
glass
```

Comment: The correct answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52850974/3832970). Other answers are not accounting for whole words.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pretty close, just readd the `\b` in the negative lookahead

```
/(\w+\b)(?!.*\1\b)/
```

See it on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/LFzFUxUTC4)

Comment: I'm wondering why `\1` apparently doesn't match the `\b` from the first group. Shouldn't `\1` match everything inside the group and not only `\w+`?

Comment: @maček Wow! Thank you so much, I have pretty much spent two days straight trying to figure this out!

Comment: @PeterStahl The reason why you have to add `\b` is to ensure that the negative lookahead matches a whole word and not just a substring, by default it matches substrings.

Comment: Just a note: `\b` is word boundary according to the word characters defined in `\w`, so there will be no word boundary around `_` in `apple_apple`.

Comment: @pemistahl: `\1` matches whatever _characters_ are found in the 1st expression, but not the assertions.

Comment: @macek its not working in python. even i can not question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew closes my question 2 times. i need help. is it possible in python?

Comment: I want to learn to build such regular expressions. I know the basics but this is from a different planet. Please help me where to start.

Answer (score 3):

For search distinct words in multiline text use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`

```
(\b\w+\b)(?![\s\S]*\b\1\b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as [maček's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14061509/1944088), but with an extra \b before the back-reference, otherwise if you had

`glass shoes door window door glasses. window glasses sunglasses`

You'd miss out a match for glasses as it finds it in the word sunglasses.

`/(\w+\b)(?!.*\b\1\b)/`

Comment: You should also add a `\b` before `\w` to not fail for `sunglasses glasses`